# How to get base url of default website?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, websites, base-url, default

I need to use the function `file_get_contents()` on default website's base URL.
Currently there are many websites in magento system.
How to get the id of default website and base URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the default website id like this:

```
$websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_default', 1);

$website = $websites->getFirstItem();
$websiteId = $website->getId();
$websiteCode = $website->getCode();
```

and you can get the base url like this:

```
$url = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('web/unsecure/base_url', 'website', $websiteCode);
```

Comment: You might need to cast $url as a string, but great answer.

Comment: With system config fallbacks, `Mage::getStoreConfig('web/unsecure/base_url', $website->getDefaultStore()->getId());`